# How to convert only some of the subviews of a UIView to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage

I have been stuck on this since yesterday. I am trying to capture only some of the `subviews` of a `UIView`. This main `UIView` has 4 `subviews` namely, the `header`, the `caption`, the `image`, and the `footer`. I am trying to capture the `caption` and the `image` only.

I have tried to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` and setting the `CGSize` from the `y` coordinate of the `caption` to the `height` of the `image`. But, it still doesn't capture only the `caption` and the `image`.

I also tried using a `UIStackView`, here, I am able to capture the `caption` and the `image` only but the `stackview` itself still remains the size of the main `UIView`. I can fix the sizing issue but the **main issue** I'm having using `UIStackView` is that when I use `addArrangedSubview:`, the `subview` being added disappears from the main `UIView`.

I'm confused about how to go about doing this? Using just `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` doesn't allow me to capture only the `caption` and the `image` and using the `UIStackView` makes the `caption` and the `image` disappear from the main `UIView`.

I hope this explanation hasn't been confusing and I'll be happy to clear someone's doubts.

Please advice me about the best way I can capture only some of the subviews from the main `UIView`.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit:
Method that worked for me, thanks to PaulDaPigeon's comments. I ended up using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`.

```
- (UIImage *) extractImageOfSubviewFromView: (UIView *)view {

  CGRect finalImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, (view.lblCaption.frame.size.height + view.image.frame.size.height));

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(finalImageRect, NO, 0.0);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextTranslateCTM(finalImageRect, 0, - view.header.frame.size.height);
  [view.layer renderInContext:context];

  UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return finalImage;

}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this seems to be with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` but instead of adding the view itself you should try `[stackView addArrangedSubview:subview.copy];` to avoid removing it from the main view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you think I should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` so that it is has only the `caption` and the `image` and not the `header` and the `footer`? I have tried to set the `CGSize` in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` so that it only includes the `caption` and the `image` but it still takes the main `UIView`

Comment: As far as I know you can't exclude subviews from the context, but if they aren't overlapping with the views you want to get you can try `UIRectClip` to cut off the pieces you don't need.
Alternatively you can temporarily hide the subviews you don't need.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my post with the method I ended up using.